# Intel compiler 17.0 with gcc 7.1/8.1

Tags: c++, compilation, icc

```
 /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/bin/intel64/icpc    -I/home/usermy/.conan/data/toolchain/1.0.5-g0a9b008/demo/test/package/c62a7e8ca4353a55148d1aa65d313056ef6659b2/include -I/home/usermy/.conan/data/PracticalSocket/1.3.9-g2de8945.M/demo/test/build/bf3ccdb63142bb66a24f13901c58796a91e7542e/include  -fvar-tracking -g -static-intel -ftz -fma -use-intel-optimized-headers -axAVX,AVX2,SSE4.2,CORE-AVX512 -xSSE4.2  -std=c++17 -O3 -gcc-name=/usr/gcc-8.1/bin/gcc -gxx-name=/usr/gcc-8.1/bin/g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/practical_socket.dir/src/PracticalSocket.cpp.o -c /home/usermy/.conan/data/PracticalSocket/1.3.9-g2de8945.M/demo/test/build/bf3ccdb63142bb66a24f13901c58796a91e7542e/src/PracticalSocket.cpp
In file included from /usr/gcc-8.1/include/c++/8.1.0/bits/move.h(55),
                 from /usr/gcc-8.1/include/c++/8.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h(59),
                 from /usr/gcc-8.1/include/c++/8.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h(64),
                 from /usr/gcc-8.1/include/c++/8.1.0/bits/char_traits.h(39),
                 from /usr/gcc-8.1/include/c++/8.1.0/string(40),
                 from /home/usermy/.conan/data/PracticalSocket/1.3.9-g2de8945.M/demo/test/build/bf3ccdb63142bb66a24f13901c58796a91e7542e/include/PracticalSocket.h(4),
                 from /home/usermy/.conan/data/PracticalSocket/1.3.9-g2de8945.M/demo/test/build/bf3ccdb63142bb66a24f13901c58796a91e7542e/src/PracticalSocket.cpp(1):
/usr/gcc-8.1/include/c++/8.1.0/type_traits(1061): error: identifier "__is_assignable" is undefined
        : public __bool_constant<__is_assignable(_Tp, _Up)>
                                 ^

In file included from /usr/gcc-8.1/include/c++/8.1.0/bits/move.h(55),
                 from /usr/gcc-8.1/include/c++/8.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h(59),
                 from /usr/gcc-8.1/include/c++/8.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h(64),
                 from /usr/gcc-8.1/include/c++/8.1.0/bits/char_traits.h(39),
                 from /usr/gcc-8.1/include/c++/8.1.0/string(40),
                 from /home/usermy/.conan/data/PracticalSocket/1.3.9-g2de8945.M/demo/test/build/bf3ccdb63142bb66a24f13901c58796a91e7542e/include/PracticalSocket.h(4),
                 from /home/usermy/.conan/data/PracticalSocket/1.3.9-g2de8945.M/demo/test/build/bf3ccdb63142bb66a24f13901c58796a91e7542e/src/PracticalSocket.cpp(1):
/usr/gcc-8.1/include/c++/8.1.0/type_traits(1061): error: type name is not allowed
        : public __bool_constant<__is_assignable(_Tp, _Up)>
```

This is what after adding the following in cmake:

```
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -O3 -gcc-name=/usr/gcc-8.1/bin/gcc -gxx-name=/usr/gcc-8.1/bin/g++")
```

Comment: So, what error do you get?

Comment: @BaummitAugen updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the release notes you will notice that Intel C++ 17 does NOT support gcc 7/8 (I don't judge you for not looking at that):

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-170-for-linux-release-notes-for-intel-parallel-studio-xe-2017

Note, Intel only provides the compiler and not the standard library, it takes that from gcc, hence the compatibility restrictions.

Note, version 18 does not support it either, hopefully that will come with 19.

Comment: 17.0 doesn't support entirety, it does support some features, 18.0 supports more features.  I am not using any non-supported feature, in fact am only using make_unique and return by `auto`.

Comment: @themagicalyang The issue is with features that GCC 8.1's libstdc++ headers make use of which aren't supported by Intel's compiler, not features you are using in your own code, specifically `__is_assignable` is a GCC intrinsic which isn't part of the C++ standard but is used internally by GCC and used in GCC's libstdc++.

Comment: Exactly, the compiler doesn't understand the standard library, it doesn't matter if you used anything special or not. If you want to use Intel C++ 17/18, you need to give it the libraries from gcc6.